# How do I display Enum Properties in a Dropdownlist?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm making a simple custom control and I would like to have a `dropdownlist` of defined custom properties and I'm perplexed as to why the code below fails to display the `enum` in the properties list of the combobox.

How do I display `enum` values in a Dropdownlist?

```
public partial class MyComboBox : ComboBox
{
    public enum Multipliers { B = 1, KB = 2, MB = 10, GB = 20, TB = 30 } { get; set; }
    public string SuperType { get; set; }
    public bool Global { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should post relevant code.

Comment: After reading this question multiple times, i think the question should be: "How to tell the VS designer PropertyGrid to show a comboBox for my Enum property?"

Answer (score 2):

You're not showing any code relating to how you're putting those enum values INTO the actual display list. You have to point the ComboBox at your enum as a DataSource (technically you have to point it at a call to `Enum.GetValues(typeof(Multipliers))`), or manually manipulate the Items collection, to get your values into the list.

Comment: // Define Enum at NameSpace Level (outside Class, where every custom control can see it)


    public enum Definitions {Default, Setting, DataColumn, Pink,Orange,Black,Yellow};


    public partial class ZionComboBox : ComboBox
    {
        public Definitions Multipliers { get; set; }

    }

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you need to do:

```
foreach (var item in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Multipliers )))
        {
            ComboBox1.Items.Add(item);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The enum is a type within MyComboBox, not a property.

You could create a property like this:

```
public partial class MyComboBox : ComboBox
{
    public enum Multipliers { B = 1, KB = 2, MB = 10, GB = 20, TB = 30 }
    public string SuperType { get; set; }
    public bool Global { get; set; }
    public Multipliers myMultiplierProperty {get; set;}
}
```

As to how those properties show up in the combo box depends a lot on the code that puts them in there.  Since you haven't given us that, I can't help if the problem is in there.

Comment: public enum Multipliers { B = 1, KB = 2, MB = 10, GB = 20, TB = 30 } { get; set; }

Comment: public enum Multipliers { B = 1, KB = 2, MB = 10, GB = 20, TB = 30 } { get; set; }

Comment: I meant for the enum type to be a property. The objective is to have the Enum as a property. Sorry about the error.

Comment: That's kinda of a blunder.  Not updating the question is a bigger one.